# How to implement utility application with navigation based flipside?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I would like to create an utility application that has a navigation based flipside, or "info",  view. What would the most efficient way to accomplish this be?  I think that i 'simply' need to make a root view controller for the flipside view...but i really only understand that conceptually...not so much how to go about it or, at least, i am not confident that i know how to go about it.

I apologize for the slightly "make my app" nature of this question i have books and books and books...but it shakes out so much differently when i want to make my own project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a view controller for the flipside view, or you could create / load a view in your app delegate. In the latter case, you can set up the delegate to respond to the info button press, and then set up a transition to the new view which will have a button (which the app delegate also responds to) that transitions back to the previous view.

There is a basic tutorial I found for this here:
http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/12222-how-do-i-create-uiview-flip-animation.html#post104474
It should be able to at least get you started.

Comment: Thank you. This video was helpful.  I also found example code for hand coding a view controller that i had forgotten. again, thank you.